# Show in url previous state after the next

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 level routing, in url it looks like `site.com/Jonny/2`. But now I need this looks `site.com/2/Jonny` or `site.com/10/Kelly`. But `index.name.page` it's next page, after `index.name`, so I can't understand how to swap 3rd and 2nd state. Is it possible?

```
$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: '',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .state('index.name', {
    url: '#:name',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/names/name.html',
        controller: 'NameCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('index.name.page', {
    url: '/:number',
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/page.html',
    controller: 'PageCtrl'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inject $state service to your controller, then in your controller...
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.changeState = function () {
     $state.go('where.ever.you.want.to.go', {stateParamKey: exampleParam});
};
```

and add ng-click to your button

HTML

```
<button ng-click="changeState()">Change State</button>
```